# IDA pro Error how to resolve this error

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, debugging, malware

```
52C187F5: The instruction at 0x52C187F5 referenced memory at 0x4. The memory could not be read -> 00000004 (exc.code c0000005, tid 672)
```

How to solve this?
I have seen sandbox reports in those the file is running fine but in my IDA this error showed anyone knows why and how to resolve it

Comment: It is an acces violation exception  if the binary is running ok outside of a debugger and refuses to work in a debugger then you can safely assume you have a lot of work ahead  identifying anti debugger algos, tricks,etc